# Check if substring of a string exists in datatable

Tags: c#, string-search

I have a DataTable like this:

```
  column1    column2
----------- ----------
1  abc d      Alpha
2  ab         Gamma
3  abc de     Harry
4  xyz        Peter
```

I want to check if a substring of a string exists in the datatable.

e.g. If the string I am looking for is "**abc defg**", record 3 should be returned (although record 1 is also a match, record 3 has more common characters in sequence).

I am not able to find any way to search as described above.
any help, guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: From an XML file. In the XML file also the quotes are spread across multiple tags.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `Regular Expression`?

Comment: @Brian , yes. But maybe I am not verse enough in regex to back search as needed in this scenario. I.e finding a substring of the search string in the data table.

Comment: Use `string.Contains` method and `string.Length` property. This is enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a two-step process.

1. Filter the table for rows that match. This can be done with the [string.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0) method. In LINQ, this would look something like:

```
const string myText = "abc defg";
IEnumerable<Row> matches = MyTable.Where(row => myText.Contains(row.Column1));
```

2. Select the longest match. In LINQ, this might look something like this.

```
Row longestMatch = matches.OrderByDescending<Row, int>(row => row.Column1.Length).First();
```